# Python flask rebar getting 404

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am getting 404

Error:

```
 curl localhost:5000/api/health
 {"message":"The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."}
```

application logs:

- Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
  127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2022 23:24:05] "GET /api/health HTTP/1.1" 404 -

code repo:

```
https://github.com/Sytten/flask-rebar-example/tree/v1/app
```

Use v1 tag:

```
 git checkout v1
```

Steps to repro

```
 git clone https://github.com/Sytten/flask-rebar-example.git
 cd flask-rebar-example/
 git checkout v1
 pip install -r requirements.txt 
 cd app
 python app.py
 
 # open new terminal and run below command 
 curl localhost:5000/api/health
```

Expected results:

```
{"status": "OK"}
```

python 3.9.5 version and Mac os

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_rebar import Rebar


rebar = Rebar()
registry = rebar.create_handler_registry(prefix='/api')


def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    rebar.init_app(app)
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run()
```

Controller.py

```
from flask_rebar import errors

from .app import registry
from .schemas import HealthSchema


@registry.handles(rule="/health", method="GET", marshal_schema=HealthSchema())
def get_health():
    return {"status": "OK"}
```

schemas.py

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema


class HealthSchema(Schema):
    status = fields.String()
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how Python imports modules.

If the `controller.py` module never gets imported, the `get_health` endpoint will never get registered.

I'm not exactly sure how that example is supposed to be started (here's the associated [blog post](https://medium.com/@emilefugulin/creating-a-production-ready-python-rest-backend-with-flask-rebar-part-1-62f498d2f077)), but what you've done (`cd app && python app.py`) won't work.

Try changing your modules around:

controller.py

```py
from rebar import HandlerRegistry
from .schemas import HealthSchema

registry = HandlerRegistry(prefix='/api')

@registry.handles(rule="/health", method="GET", marshal_schema=HealthSchema())
def get_health():
    return {"status": "OK"}
```

app.py

```py
from rebar import Rebar
from controller import registry

def create_app() -> Flask:
    rebar = Rebar()
    rebar.add_handler_registry(registry)
    app = Flask(__name__)
    rebar.init_app(app)
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run()
```